# Why connection with SignalR Hub not working in release mode

Tags: flutter

In my app I'm setting connection with SignalR and during developing everything works fine, it means that I can receive events from server and then handle it and it was like that in release mode for some time... because today errors occurs and the same errors in two libraries [signalr_core (pub.dev)](https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_core) and [signalr_netcore (pub.dev)](https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_netcore) (because of problems I decided to test other package). I also tried `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`

```dart
  Future<void> startConnection() async {
    hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(
          'url/hub/chat',
          options: HttpConnectionOptions(
            transport: HttpTransportType.ServerSentEvents,
          ),
        )
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();

    await hubConnection.start();

    chatStore.connectionId = hubConnection.connectionId;

    hubConnection.on('LoadChat', (arguments) {
      chatStore.addMessages(arguments);
    });
  }
```

I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` from almost beginning, and I found some advices to add content to `proguard-rules.pro` and `build.gradle`, but it didn't work.

proguard-rules.pro:

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-keep class microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.** { *; }
```

build.gradle:

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 
        }
    }
```

Error log:

```dart
E/flutter (21355): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Stack Overflow
E/flutter (21355): #0      _RegExp._ExecuteMatch (dart:core-patch/regexp_patch.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #1      _RegExp.firstMatch (dart:core-patch/regexp_patch.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #2      EventSourceTransformer.bind.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:sse_client/src/event_source_transformer.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #5      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #8      _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #9      _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #10     _LineSplitterSink._addLines (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #11     _LineSplitterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #12     StringConversionSinkMixin.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #13     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #16     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #18     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #19     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #20     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #21     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #22     _StringAdapterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #23     _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #24     _Utf8ConversionSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #25     _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #26     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #27     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #28     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #29     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #30     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #31     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #32     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #33     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #34     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #35     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #36     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): ...
E/flutter (21355): ...
E/flutter (21355): #44     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #45     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #46     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #47     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #48     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #49     _HttpParser._doParse (dart:_http/http_parser.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #50     _HttpParser._parse (dart:_http/http_parser.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #51     _HttpParser._onData (dart:_http/http_parser.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #52     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #53     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #54     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #55     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #56     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #57     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #58     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #59     _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #60     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #61     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #62     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #63     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #64     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #65     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #66     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #67     _RawSecureSocket._sendReadEvent (dart:io/secure_socket.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #68     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #69     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #70     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #71     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #72     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #73     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #74     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #75     SemanticsConfiguration._addArgumentlessAction.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/semantics/semantics.dart)     
E/flutter (21355): #76     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #77     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart)
E/flutter (21355): #78     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart)
```

pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
dependencies:
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  collection: ^1.15.0
  connectivity_plus: ^2.2.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  decimal: ^2.0.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter    
  flutter_mobx: ^2.0.3+2
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.0
  flutter_zoom_drawer: ^2.1.2
  http: ^0.13.4
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
  internet_connection_checker: ^0.0.1+3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  mobx: ^2.0.6+1
  provider: ^6.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  signalr_core: ^1.1.1
  signalr_netcore: ^1.2.3+1
  skeletons: ^0.0.3
  top_snackbar_flutter: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.1.7
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  lint: ^1.0.0
  mobx_codegen: ^2.0.5+2
```

Comment: I remember I got this `Stack Overflow` error once. That was because my application was stock in an infinite loop. I'm not sure about it but check if your application is stock in an infinite loop somewhere in your code!

Comment: I can't find any problems with infinity loop in my code. Do you have any ideas why it's not happening in debug mode?

Comment: Having the same problem in native Android, bug only happening in release mode. Did you find any solution @MonkeyD.Teach ?

Comment: @Itoun I used other library to make connection with SignalR. Here is the library and the version: signalr_pure: ^1.0.0+3